# Finding largest of N numbers using assembly language

Tags: sorting, assembly, emu8086

Hi I'm a beginner at assembly language. I'm trying to find the largest out of N user defined numbers. The program does find the largest number out of the user defined list but displays the result with 256 added to it every time.

```
    code segment
assume cs:code, ds:data
start:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
printstring msg1         ;how many numbers
readnum num              
mov si,offset ntable
mov ch,00
mov cl,num

read:                    ;function to get input numbers
printstring msg2
readnum temp
mov al,temp
mov [si],al
inc si
loop read

mov si,offset ntable     ;load offset of ntable in source index
mov al, [si]
mov ch,00
mov cl,num

check:
cmp al,[si+1]
jnl next                
mov al,[si+1]             

next:
inc si
dec cl
cmp cl,00
jge check



exit:
mov si,offset result
mov [si],al
```

Comment: Thanks for editing to replace the images with a `code block`, but it doesn't look complete.  `ntable` isn't defined anywhere, and I don't see any code that would print an integer as a string of ASCII digits. So not a [mcve]. Multiplied by 256 sounds like you output a 16-bit number with your 8-bit number as the high half.

Answer (score 0):

> **The program does find the largest number out of the user defined list** but displays the result with 256 added to it every time.

The code manages to find **a** largest number but whether that is **the** largest number depends on whatever garbage there is following your numbers array! Your *check* loop is doing 2 iterations too many.

> ```
> mov si,offset ntable     ;load offset of ntable in source index
> mov al, [si]
> mov ch,00
> mov cl,num
>
> check:
> cmp al,[si+1]
> jnl next                
> mov al,[si+1]             
>
> next:
> inc si
> dec cl
> cmp cl,00
> jge check
> ```

Consider an input of two numbers: eg. 15 and 38, where a single comparison will be enough to establish the maximum. The *num* variable will hold 2, so that's what you load in CL.
Because you continue the loop for as long as CL is greater or equal to zero, you get next 3 iterations:

```
             ntable
             v
AL=15 CL=2   15 38 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ...
             =====
             ^
             SI

AL=38 CL=1   15 38 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ...
                =====
                ^
                SI

AL=.. CL=0   15 38 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ...
                   =====
                   ^
                   SI

AL=.. CL=-1  15 38 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ...

                      ^
                      SI
```

> The program does find the largest number out of the user defined list but **displays the result with 256 added to it every time**.

The +256 comes from not having reset the AH register before tackling the conversion from number to text.
Your conversion routine *h2a* uses the word-sized division `div bx` that will divide DX:AX by BX. You have provided it AL and you have cleared DX, **but AH still contains the value 01h from the most recent invokation of the DOS.GetCharacter function that is part of the *readnum* macro**.

---

The improved code:

```
  mov  si, offset ntable
  mov  al, [si]
  mov  cl, num     ; 1 or more
  jmp  begin       <<< part 1 of this answer
check:
  cmp  al, [si+1]
  jnl  next                
  mov  al, [si+1]             
next:
  inc  si
begin:             <<< part 1 of this answer
  dec  cl          <<< part 1 of this answer
  jnz  check       <<< part 1 of this answer
done:
  mov  ah, 0       <<< part 2 of this answer
```